# Alternative to Miro Video Converter for Linux?

Tags: software-rec, video, free-software, conversion

Back in the Windows/Mac days, I used the wonderfully easy to use Miro Video Converter to convert videos I have into either the more open and Freerer Theora or WebM formats. Two problems:

(1) No Linux binary that I could use.

(2) No advanced options that let me control the conversion process, such as embedding subtitles.

Is there an alternative FLOSS on Linux that does this? Thanks!

Comment: Do the sources of software in [Where can I find Software for Unix/Linux that does X?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/where-can-i-find-software-for-unix-linux-that-does-x) help?

Comment: Does help, I will try my search there. Thanks! In the meantime, if you know of a specific one that's good, please let me know, too.

Comment: Have to tried VLC?  In general I find that VLC covers most of these sorts of needs.

Comment: I don't remember how easy/hard it was to add subtitles, but there's [`ffmpeg2theora`](http://v2v.cc/~j/ffmpeg2theora/), which attempts to be an "any to Ogg Theora" converter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest a frontend to `ffmpeg`. There are several out there, for example

- [Sinthgunt](http://code.google.com/p/sinthgunt/)
- [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)
- [Transcoder](http://transcoder84.sourceforge.net/)
- [HyperVideo Converter](http://gtk-apps.org/content/show.php/Hyper+Video+Converter?content=88970)

Sinthgunt looks the most promising to me - it looks relatively discoverable, and comes with loads of preset formats to convert into.

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg does both, of course............

Comment: OP mentioned `easy`, and by that I think he is thinking GUI. So maybe you could at least point to a tutorial that de-mystifies ffmpeg.

Comment: @Tshepang - I would hope that anyone posting here would not require a GUI to make things easy for them.

Comment: Why's that? There's many tasks that are made easy by using a GUI.

Comment: How difficult can this be?: ffmpeg -i video.avi video.webm

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on the device/format targets, but [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is also an interesting tool for such tasks. It is a bit picky about output formats (only mkv and m4v), but works great if you can read those.